# Select() method returns a warning

Tags: html, dart, dart2js

I need a Select All button for a textarea. It works with this code, but I get a warning from Dart2js:

```
querySelector('#select-all-button').onClick.listen((e) {
//e.preventDefault();
querySelector('#textarea-target').select();
});

Warning: No method named 'select' in class 'Element'.
  querySelector('#textarea-target').select();
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of `querySelector()` is `dynamic` AFAIR. You need to explicitly tell the analyzer what type this will return

```
(document.querySelector('textarea') as TextAreaElement).select();
```

Try it on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/d28cc428b7e1f87dccc5)

Comment: Not dynamic, Element. But it's being interpreted as the subclass.

Comment: A bit more complicated than JavaScript, but it works. Thanks.

Comment: The code would run fine without the cast, the analyzer just warns you that the return type declared by `querySelector()` isn't know to have a `select` method. You can safely ignore the warning. If you give the analyzer the information that you expect an `TextAreaElement`, then it can provide useful hints and better autocompletion further down your code.